# hapijs joi validation , just validate one field and to allow any field

Tags: hapi.js, joi

I want to validate one field and to allow another fields without validation; by example just to validate: "firstname" field. In my code when I  comment 'payload', hapi allow me to record any field, when I uncomment 'payload' hapijs dont allow me record any field, but I want just to validate by example 'firstname' to be a 'string' and let rest of fields to allow. I plan to have variable fields accord a database config, so I'm going to just validate some fixed fields and let to save another variable fields controlled in the front end, not in the backend

```
  config: {
      validate: {
         /* payload: {
            firstname: Joi.string(),
            lastname: Joi.string()
            ...anothers fields...

          }*/
      }
  }
```

UPDATED:
thanks to Robert K. Bell, i've adapted the solution is to add 'validate':

```
  config: {
      validate: {
         options: {
            allowUnknown: true
          },
          payload: {
            firstname: Joi.string()
          }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You may be looking for the [`.unknown()` method:](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v9.0.4/API.md#objectunknownallow)

#### `object.unknown([allow])`

Overrides the handling of unknown keys for the scope of the current object only (does not apply to children) where:

- `allow` - if `false`, unknown keys are not allowed, otherwise unknown keys are ignored.

`js
const schema = Joi.object({ a: Joi.any() }).unknown();`

Comment: thanks , i'm going to edit my answer, accord to my config ; i must use 'options' but it's the same unknown() method

Answer (score 13):

```
  config: {
      validate: {
        payload: Joi.object({
            'firstname': Joi.string(),
        }).options({ allowUnknown: true })
      }
  }
```

Instead of adding validation fields in the validate validate the payload directly using Joi object. Which accepts allowUnknown true using this it will only validated only the fields which are mentioned in the Joi Object.

Comment: Could you please add an explanation?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

.... {allowUnknown: true}

as per doc, there is "options" method can be used while creating Joi objectSchema.

i.e. tobe very simple UI can send many keys but use only 2 keys email, and password. so a validation function can be defined as this.

```
function validateUserForSubscription(input) {
    const schema = Joi.object({
        email: Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required().email(),
        password: Joi.string().min(5).max(1024).required()
    }).options({ allowUnknown: true });

    return schema.validate(input);
}
```

in other file use it like this.

> const isValidUser = validateUserForSubscription(req.body);